# Apple Shortcuts Progress Bar?

Tags: shortcuts-app

I made a shortcut that enhances images in PixelMator Pro from the Quick Actions menu. It works great but I don't see anywhere the progress of this shortcut. If there are a hundred images it can take quite a while and I would like to see how many images it has finished. Is there a way to add some kind of progress bar or is there any other way to see the progress of shortcut as it is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While a shortcut is running, the Shortcuts menulet changes from an outline to 'filled-in', as here:

[image]

If you click on it, it will show you which shortcut is running, and a progress 'clock'.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have menu bar hiding util and it was hidden:)